# NSwag generates base class even though JsonSchemaFlattenAttribute is set

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, swagger, swagger-codegen, nswag

I am using NSwag for my ASP.NET Core web api project and just can't get it to work. What I'm trying to do is to exclude some of the base properties of **IdentityUser**. Here is my custom user class:

```
[DataContract]
[JsonSchemaFlattenAttribute]
public class User : IdentityUser
{
    // Overridden variables
    [DataMember( Name = "id" )]
    [PersonalData]
    public new string Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember( Name = "email" )]
    [ProtectedPersonalData]
    public new string Email { get; set; }

    [IgnoreDataMember]
    [JsonSchemaIgnoreAttribute]
    public new DateTimeOffset? LockoutEnd { get; set; }

    [PersonalData]
    [IgnoreDataMember]
    [JsonSchemaIgnoreAttribute]
    public new bool TwoFactorEnabled { get; set; }

    [PersonalData]
    [IgnoreDataMember]
    [JsonSchemaIgnoreAttribute]
    public new bool PhoneNumberConfirmed { get; set; }

    [ProtectedPersonalData]
    [IgnoreDataMember]
    [JsonSchemaIgnoreAttribute]
    public new string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

    [IgnoreDataMember]
    [JsonSchemaIgnoreAttribute]
    public new string ConcurrencyStamp { get; set; }

    [IgnoreDataMember]
    [JsonSchemaIgnoreAttribute]
    public new string SecurityStamp { get; set; }

    [IgnoreDataMember]
    [JsonSchemaIgnoreAttribute]
    public new string PasswordHash { get; set; }

    [PersonalData]
    [IgnoreDataMember]
    [JsonSchemaIgnoreAttribute]
    public new bool EmailConfirmed { get; set; }

    [IgnoreDataMember]
    [JsonSchemaIgnoreAttribute]
    public new string NormalizedEmail { get; set; }

    [IgnoreDataMember]
    [JsonSchemaIgnoreAttribute]
    public new string NormalizedUserName { get; set; }

    [ProtectedPersonalData]
    [IgnoreDataMember]
    [JsonSchemaIgnoreAttribute]
    public new string UserName { get; set; }

    [IgnoreDataMember]
    [JsonSchemaIgnoreAttribute]
    public new bool LockoutEnabled { get; set; }

    [IgnoreDataMember]
    [JsonSchemaIgnoreAttribute]
    public new int AccessFailedCount { get; set; }

    // Custom variables
    [DataMember( Name = "date_joined_utc" )]
    public DateTime DateJoinedUtc { get; set; }

    [IgnoreDataMember]
    [JsonSchemaIgnoreAttribute]
    public virtual ICollection<RefreshToken> RefreshTokens { get; set; }

    // Optimistic concurrency
    [Timestamp]
    [IgnoreDataMember]
    [JsonSchemaIgnoreAttribute]
    public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }
}
```

Which generates:

```
"User": {
  "type": "object",
  "required": [
    "dateJoinedUtc"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "id": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "email": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "dateJoinedUtc": {
      "type": "string",
      "format": "date-time"
    }
  },
  "allOf": [
    {
      "$ref": "#/definitions/IdentityUserOfString"
    },
    {}
  ]
},
"IdentityUserOfString": {
  "type": "object",
  "required": [
    "emailConfirmed",
    "phoneNumberConfirmed",
    "twoFactorEnabled",
    "lockoutEnabled",
    "accessFailedCount"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "id": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "userName": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "normalizedUserName": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "email": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "normalizedEmail": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "emailConfirmed": {
      "type": "boolean"
    },
    "passwordHash": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "securityStamp": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "concurrencyStamp": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "phoneNumber": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "phoneNumberConfirmed": {
      "type": "boolean"
    },
    "twoFactorEnabled": {
      "type": "boolean"
    },
    "lockoutEnd": {
      "type": "string",
      "format": "date-time"
    },
    "lockoutEnabled": {
      "type": "boolean"
    },
    "accessFailedCount": {
      "type": "integer",
      "format": "int32"
    }
  }
},
```

My understanding of **JsonSchemaFlattenAttribute** is that it should exclude the base classes and put every property in the derived class. So why is the class **IdentityUserOfString** generated? What am I missing?

Comment: Here is the source code about [JsonSchemaFlattenAttribute](https://github.com/RicoSuter/NJsonSchema/blob/master/src/NJsonSchema/Annotations/JsonSchemaFlattenAttribute.cs).In the [link](https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag/issues/1980),`SeppPenner`  says it;s what  what he was searching for.Maybe JsonSchemaFlattenAttribute can only work for custom bas e class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason setting **OpenApiIgnore** on the User class solved it:

```
[DataContract]
//[JsonSchemaFlattenAttribute]
[OpenApiIgnore]
public class User : IdentityUser
```

Generates:

```
"User": {
  "type": "object",
  "required": [
    "dateJoinedUtc"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "id": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "email": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "dateJoinedUtc": {
      "type": "string",
      "format": "date-time"
    }
  }
},
```